# About formatting new EBS volume on Amazon AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I don't have much experience with Linux and mounting/unmounting things. I'm using Amazon AWS, have booting up EC2 with Ubuntu image, and have attached a new EBS volume to the EC2. From the dashboard, I can see that the volume is attached to `:/dev/sda1`.

Now, I see from [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) from Amazon that the path will likely be changed by the kernel. So it's most likely that my `/dev/sda1` device will be mounted on, maybe, `/dev/xvda1`.

So I logged in using terminal. I do `ls /dev/` and I indeed see `xvda1` on there. But I also see `xvda`. Now I want to format the device. But I don't know if the unformatted device is attached to `xvda1` or `xvda`. I cannot list the content of `/dev/xvda1` and `/dev/xvda` (it says `ls: cannot access /dev/xvda1/: Not a directory`). I guess I have to format it first.

I tried to format using `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvda1`. It says: `/dev/xvda1 is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!`.

I tried to format using `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvda`. It says: `/dev/xvda is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`

How can I format the volume?

EDIT:

The result of `lsblk` command:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
`-xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

I then tried to use the command `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvda`, but the same error message appears: `/dev/xvda is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`

When I tried to use the command `mount /dev/xvda /webserver`, error message appears: `mount: /dev/xvda already mounted or /webserver busy`. Some website indicate that this also probably because a corrupted or unformatted file system. So I guess I have to be able to format it first before able to mount it.

Comment: Note how `xvda` shows `disk` and `xvda1` shows `part` -- partition, and the little arrow under `xvda`  `xvda1` is the first (and only) *partition* on the `xvda` *disk.*  Stay away from both of these -- this is your root partition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you are trying to format /dev/xvda1, which is root device. Why ??

Second if you have added a new EBS, then follow below steps.

**List Block Device's**

This will give you list of block device attached to your EC2 which will look like

```
[ec2-user ~]$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdf  202:80   0  100G  0 disk
xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 disk /
```

Out of this xvda1 is the / (root) and xvdf is the one that you need to format and mount ( for the new EBS)

**Format Device**

```
 sudo mkfs -t ext4 device_name   # device_name is xvdf here
```

**Create a Mount Point**

```
 sudo mkdir /mount_point
```

**Mount the Volume**

```
 sudo mount device_name mount_point  # here device_name is /dev/xvdf
```

**Make an entry in /etc/fstab**

```
 device_name  mount_point  file_system_type  fs_mntops  fs_freq  fs_passno
```

**Execute**

```
 sudo mount -a
```

This will read your /etc/fstab file and if it's OK. it will mount the EBS to mount_point

Comment: Hi. I have edit my question adding details regarding your steps. Please review. Thanks.

Comment: You can't format /dev/xvda1. It's not possible.. Since you have added a new EBS which is xvdf which requires formatting and mounting

Comment: Hi. I'm not formatting `xvda1`. I'm formatting `xvda`. The result of `lsblk` shows that the device available to mount is `xvda`. There's no mention of `xvdf` anywhere in the system. When I tried to do `ls /dev/xvdf`, it says: `ls: cannot access /dev/xvdf: No such file or directory`.

Comment: 1) There is no xvda it's xvda1 ( AWS do this somehow)
2) ls /dev/xvdf will not work..Since this is a raw disk, you didn't format and mount.
You need to take car only of /dev/xvdf not /dev/xvda1 ( Root device )

Comment: You should make sure to check the status of the "new" volume with sudo file -s /dev/xvdf.  If you get back /dev/xvdf: data than, it's a "blank" volume and it's safe to format.  If you get back something like /dev/xvdf1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=1701d228-e1bd-4094-a14c-8c64d6819362 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files), than it has data on it.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: @Vikash Hi. The xvdf device you mentioned, it's not appeared on `lsblk` (see my original question under the EDIT: part for the result of `lsblk`). I also tried to do Brooks' command to `sudo file -s /dev/xvdf`, and I get the result `/dev/xvdf: ERROR: cannot open `/dev/xvdf' (No such file or directory)`. I'm pretty positive that there's no `xvdf` device on the system. On the dashboard, AWS told me that the volume is mounted on `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: The result of `sudo file -s /dev/xvda` is: `/dev/xvda: x86 boot sector`.

Comment: The result of `sudo file -s /dev/xvda1` is: `/dev/xvda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=0a76513a-37fc-43df-9833-34f8f9598ada, volume name "cloudimg-rootfs" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)`

Comment: Does this means my EBS volume maybe is not attached? I only have one EC2 and one EBS, and AWS console says that the EBS volume is attached to the correct instance ID of my EC2...